# Sanitizing a query that accept user-selected conditions

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an internal tool I'm working on, that should allow users to build a query that runs on our datalake DB.

We are using Snowflake DB, accessing it using python (with snowflake-connector-python) and querying using raw queries (no ORM) .

The users are internal users, and the query has a hardcoded limit of times and # of records.
The query building happens on a form where the users can enter the contents of the select clause and the WHERE clause.

I am aware of the fact that when allowing a user to enter a free-text part of the query, there's an unavoidable risk.

My question here is how can I minimize that risk at the query level - the user itself should already be limited to only do SELECTs, and their SELECT shouldn't be able to DDoS the DB because of the hard limit on returned records.

From what I gather about query parameters, I can't use it to create a dynamic WHERE clause, because I need to specify the columns (i.e. `SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE COL1={param1} AND COL2={param2}`).

Other than regex-ing the query to find semicolons and `--`, is there anything else I can do?

Thank you.

Comment: Specify the DBMS used. What programming language do you use? Do you use any ORM? Many of them provide approaches for creating dynamic queries with full injection protection.

Comment: Database permission. Select only for the process running this query.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Im using Snowflake DB. no ORM, raw queries . using the python snowflake connector. 
Will also edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Horaciux recommends in their comment: Use Snowflake's RBAC (permissions) model.

- Create a user for your app.
- Give this user only one role, that's only allowed to read data from the permitted tables.
- Have the app connect to Snowflake using that user and the given role.
- Make sure the user doesn't have other roles (to prevent some evil escaping user input somehow changing the role).

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-overview